# Mybatis to map automatically to support dot

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper, mybatis-sql

```
 <select id="findAll" resultType="com.pojo.Pod">

select 
 a.id,
 a.name,
 a.create_date,
 a.user_name as 'user.name'
 a.user_phone as 'user.phone'
from t_pod a

</select>
```

**configuration**

mybatis.configuration.map-underscore-to-camel-case=true

I want mybatis to support dot, auto mapping.

```
class Pod {
  int id;
  String name;
  User user;
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this is possible.